# Performance Max data in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

we are working with Google Big Query data with Google Ads native connector which transfers data from Google Ads to Google Big Query. We see all data about products in Smart Shopping/Shopping campaigns, but we have no data about products in Performance Max campaigns in Big Query.

Does anyone knows how to get data from these campaigns to Google Big Query or when it will be available?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Google works on an update for Google Ads DataTransfer Service. It still use the old API v201809.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can now get the data transfer based on the new api v11:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/google-ads-transfer